# How to count number of backslash "\" in a string

Tags: c#, winforms

How to count the number of backslashes in a string?
I've tried the following, but none of them worked.

```
string s = @"\a\a\n\u\u0013((((\a\b\n"; // output must be 8
int count = s.Count(a => a == "\\"); // Operator == cant be applied of type char & string
int count = s.Count(a => a == "\"); // newline in constant
int count = s.Split('\\').Length // it doesnt count
```

Comment: For each of your problems a simple google search would yield tons of posts, like the ones I choose to close your question with. Please be more careful next time *before* asking a question.

Answer (score 4):

Your first attempt was nearly correct;  but you need to compare a character and a character, not a character and a string.

Your code should be:

```
int count = s.Count(a => a == '\\');
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion and there's no error in it but the result is still zero

Comment: @Vincent Then you must be testing against another string. I've run the code verbatim, and it prints 8.